# Loopback and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I've been trying to create a collection that contains an array of objects in loopback.

I want a store data formatted like this:

```
{
  id: "16356135616aaasad", //autogenerated by mongo
  "name" : "a name",
  "valores": [
    {"valor": 567, "fecha": "2016-08-18T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"valor": 569, "fecha": "2016-08-19T00:00:00.000Z"},
    ...
  ]
}
```

I have the following configuration in loopback:

**indicador.json**

```
{
  "name": "Indicador",
  "plural": "indicadores",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "autoId": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "nombre": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "historico": {
      "type": "embedsMany",
      "model": "Valor"
    }
  }
}
```

this is a base collection associated to another model (not persistent)
**valor.json**

```
{
  "name": "Valor",
  "plural": "valores",
  "base": "Model",
  "properties": {
    "valor": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "fecha": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
```

The problem it's when i try to send a post to the endpoint. If i send this data

```
{
  "nombre": "UF",
  "valores": [
    { 
      "valor": 0,
      "fecha": "2016-08-18"
    }
  ]
}
```

The API responses this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "status": 422,
    "message": "The `Indicador` instance is not valid. Details: `valores` contains invalid item at index `0`: `id` is blank (value: [ { valor: 0, fecha: 2016...} ]).",
    "statusCode": 422,
    "details": {
      "context": "Indicador",
      "codes": {
        "valores": [
          "invalid"
        ]
      },
      "messages": {
        "valores": [
          "contains invalid item at index `0`: `id` is blank"
        ]
      }
    },
    "stack": "ValidationError: The `Indicador` instance is not valid. Details: `valores` contains invalid item at index `0`: `id` is blank (value: [ { valor: 0, fecha: 2016...} ]).\n    at /home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:322:12\n    at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (/home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:492:11)\n    at ModelConstructor.next (/home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:81:12)\n    at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (/home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:489:23)\n    at ModelConstructor.trigger (/home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:71:12)\n    at ModelConstructor.Validatable.isValid (/home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:455:8)\n    at /home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:318:9\n    at doNotify (/home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:98:49)\n    at doNotify (/home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:98:49)\n    at doNotify (/home/dev/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:98:49)"
  }
}
```

**¿Why i get this error?**

The id inside the objects of the array that I need isn't necessary for me. I don't understand why happen this.

Comment: Hello, try to set  "idInjection": to false in the indicator model.

Comment: @mrdotb I get the same error. this is very weird.

Comment: I never use embedOne with loopback. Consider using hasMany. Or nest valored in the Indicator model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that embedded model doe not need `id`

```
"relations": {
    "historico": {
      "type": "embedsMany",
      "model": "Valor",
      "options": {
        "forceId": false,
        "validate": true,
        "persistent": false
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: this does not work for me. I don't understand this behaviour. It's very weird.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "defaultFn":"uuid" to the id property in the json of the model that is going to be embeded in order to have the id generated. In your case it will look like the following:

```
{
  "name": "Valor",
  "plural": "valores",
  "base": "Model",
  "properties": {
    "id":{
      "type": "string",
      "defaultFn":"uuid",
      "id":true
     },
    "valor": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "fecha": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
```